# I’m having trouble finding the bug

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up this list item directly underneath the hours div tag. My list item is pushed just a little to the right, and I cant seem to find out why. My HTML and CSS skills are beginner.

I did follow from a YouTube video, but don't know what I did wrong.

```css
#hero h2{
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative; 

}

#hero ul li{
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.hours ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hours li{
  list-style: none;
}

.hours li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: .5rem;
  display: block; 

}
```

```html
    <section id="hero">
  <div class="hero container">
    <div class="">
      <h2>Hours</h2>
      <div class="hours">
       <ul>
        <li><b>Mon-thurs: </b>9am - 5pm<span></span></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Note that you're missing a closing div for `<div class="hero container">`. Also, this is a great time to learn some basic debugging. Your list items have default padding on them that your dev tools inspector would show you

Comment: If you have a new question to ask, ask in a new question, don't edit an existing one with your new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.hours li` have `padding: .5rem` that's why.
You might set `padding:.5rem 0` to align better.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#hero h2 {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

#hero ul li {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.hours ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hours li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hours li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <div class="hero container">
    <div class="">
      <h2>Hours</h2>
      <div class="hours">
        <ul>
          <li><b>Mon-thurs: </b>9am - 5pm<span></span></li>
          <li><b>Mon-thurs: </b>9am - 5pm<span></span></li>
          <li><b>Mon-thurs: </b>9am - 5pm<span></span></li>
          <li><b>Mon-thurs: </b>9am - 5pm<span></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```